# Entity Framework 7 and ASP MVC 5 - simple tasks

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am sorry if I am asking something that has an obvious answer, but I have spent and entire day searching for resources on the subject and I fail to find or understand how to do a few basic thing with EF7.

So, here is my question.

I have an ASP MVC 5 (VNEXT) website and I am using Entity Framework 7. I have an existing database, thus I am working database-first.

So far everything was fine. I installed everything required to get my DNX EF commands up and working; I scaffolded a dbContext and I got all my tables as classes and a dbContext class.

Everything fine, all well. I was happy and continuing with my work. 
However, I got to a point where I wanted to make a property of one of the generated (table) classes Required, because I use jQuery unobtrusive validation.

I have the following resource as a reference: http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/required-optional.html

My first wonder is, according to this source, in the FluentAPI the property has been marked as .IsRequired(). I believe, making it required here is a whole other thing that has nothing to do with unobtrusive validation. So, the next thing explained is simply - go to your class and add the Required data annotation.

This is all fine and well, and after adding it, it works as it should. 
But I immediately wondered - well, I am modifying the generated classes, am I not going to lose those changes once I update the model?

Which leads me to my final problem - I searched for a long time, I even played with the help menu of DNX EF, but I am unable to find the right way to update the dbContext and generated models after I make changes to the database.

I believed this to be something quite trivial but to my surprise I am unable to find a resource explaining how to do the update.

Can you point me in the right direction, and tell me how to update EF generated models and context after I make changes in the database schema, and what is the best way to add annotations to the properties of the generated classes?

Comment: Read up on DTO (Data Transfer Object) and use it as the Model in the MVC framework. dont use entities as MCV models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general consensus is that you shouldn't use your database entities as input from users directly. Instead, use ViewModels, verify those against your validation rules, then map them to database transactions.

Comment: thank you, I would keep in mind that I should use ViewModels. But do you have any idea how to update the model after I make changes ?

Comment: It's still MVC even if you use view models. MVVM doesn't really work in a cient-server scenario. You just update your model from your viewmodel in the controller. @astian there's a nuget package called `AutoMapper` which could help.

Answer (score 1):

As asp.net MVC developer I use database first and updating database is a big head ache so I use [Metadata](http://%20%20[1]:%20http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation) approach and create ViewModels which helps allot.